# Comment Section in Notion

Tags: notion-api

So, I have like a little Financial Analysis blog on Notion where I share all my insights. I want to integrate a comment system for people leave their comment on my insight (no matter if they are or not registered on Notion).

I want to use Angular + Firebase.
So, in Firebase I will save all the comments in a collection called "comments" (of course) and each documentID shall be the pageID; that way the user can see and post the comments of the requested page.

For example: if they go through December 4 analysis they shall see only the comments of this particular day.

But.. I don't know how to do that. Is there a way to get the pageID or to get all the database of the requested page and then with that databaseID get the pageID to use that value for saving the data in firebase?

Thanks in advance!